# When to refetch data from server Vs when to just update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, use-state, react-query

Let's say I am displaying a list of Users in my component. There is a `Delete Icon` to delete individual users.

There are 2 ways to achieve this in React.

**Using Client State**

1. We will fetch the list of users using `useEffect` inside the User component and store it in a local state using `useState`.
2. Once User clicks on the delete button, make some api call and just update the state(by removing the deleted user) on the success callback. `(Maybe we can go for an optimistic ui update also without waiting for server confirmation. if the server fails revert the update. This is a separate topic.)`
3. In this case we are not making another call to server to refetch the items.

**Using Server State (react-query way)**

1. We will fetch the list of items using `useQuery` inside the User component.
2. Once user clicks on the delete button, we will call the `mutateAsync` function and `onSuccess` callback will invalidate the cache.
3. Invalidating cache will refetch all users from the cart by making a fresh GET call.

Both the ways work perfectly fine. I have recently seen a lot of applause for `react-query`.

But with the 2nd approach are not we making a lot of extra server calls instead of just updating the state? This is applicable to multiple other scenarios also.

Could you someone please explain to me why still people prefer `react-query`?

Comment: This is the debate over "optimistic" vs "pessimistic" rendering. Depending on your application requirements you might be able to make a choice between the two, but it's not inherently clear which one is preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

react-query has many advantages for data fetching - being a global state manager is likely the biggest: You can call useQuery with the same key in multiple components and you’ll get data from the cache instantly and a background update.

For mutations, it’s nice that it tracks the loading state automatically, so that you can show a spinner while updating. You can also avoid the refetch if your mutation returns the server result. Then you can just update the cache manually. If it’s about deletion, you can also manually delete it like in the first example. react-query doesn’t force you to refetch. Have a look here as well: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses

Answer (score 0):

if you are going big you must consider using "SERVER-CACHING (using redis,...)" to never hit database for every little change!

e.g. if you have a todo list , do you really want to hit database for every mutation(add-toggle-edit-remove)in your list! or you can just easily update cache manually based on mutation result and also cache data in server (10s, 1m , ...).

in first approach the database `query` load is (1 => initial query) but second is (n => query for every mutation and there is no server caching).